# Extracting multiple groups of child nodes with XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

I and need to use XPATH to extract in groups of 100 from an XML extract. The XML data that is being brought in has about 1000 child nodes. I simply need to pull sets of 100 out of the overall data until it runs through all 1000 child nodes. Is there an XPATH expression that can do that?
I was using **'//cleanup/name[position() <= 100]'**, but obviously that only used the first 100 nodes every time and would not run though the entire 1000.

```
<cleanup> 
<name>object1</name>
<name>object2</name>
<name>object3</name>
<name>object4</name>
<name>object5</name>
<name>object6</name>
</cleanup>
```

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure an 'XPath only' solution is the most appropiate way to do this.
But, to pull sets of nodes, you can combine multiple arguments with `and`. 1000 nodes, 10 expressions.

```
//name[position()>0 and position ()<101]
//name[position()>99 and position ()<201]
//name[position()>199 and position ()<301]
//name[position()>299 and position ()<401]
//name[position()>399 and position ()<501]
//name[position()>499 and position ()<601]
//name[position()>599 and position ()<701]
//name[position()>699 and position ()<801]
//name[position()>799 and position ()<901]
//name[position()>899 and position ()<1001]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm somewhat limited to Xpath. But, thank you I think that will work for my case.